# Troubles with saving UserCreationForm in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have my registration view, that uses `UserCreationForm`. Here it is:

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
        if form.is_valid:
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            logout(request)
        form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {'form':form,}
    return render(request, "register.html",context)
```

But somehow when I try to create new user, I get `AttributeError`, that says "
'UserCreationForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'" even though I don't have any calls of `cleaned_data` whatsoever. I tried to create my custom registration form which used `cleaned_data`, but I threw this away and wiped my custom form from the project completely. Why could this happen?

P.S. The line that causes problems according to my Django debug return is `user = form.save()`

Comment: Instead of `form.is_valid` it is supposed to be `form.is_valid()`. (You need to _call_ the method) `form.save()` will internally use `cleaned_data` of the form to save the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### When handling form submission in function based views you need to pass the request data to the form constructor in order to get a populated form instance.

Calling form.is_valid() (*note this is actually a method as [Abdul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) pointed out*) will execute the form's clean method which is responsible for storing the clean data in form.cleaned_data. Again, as [Abdul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) pointed out form.save() internally uses form.cleaned_data meaning that the form needs to be cleaned and validated before saving.

```py
def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)  # instantiate form with request data
        if form.is_valid():                    # validate and clean form
        ...
```

This is really nicely explained in [the documentation on working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#working-with-forms). Take a look at this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#the-view) but I would really recommend skimming through the entire document to get a better idea of how forms in django work/are used.